# Swift 2, UICollectionView not dequeuing properly with correct identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

This is Xcode 7.3.1, swift 2

I have a single view controller with a UICollectionView that is a subview of a UIView.  The collection view has a cell that has the identifier "NumberCell".

Here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath in my ViewController

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NumberCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? NumberCell {
        let currentNumber = indexPath.row + 1
        cell.configureCell(currentNumber)

        cell.numberBtn.tag = currentNumber;
        cell.numberBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.playerClickedButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        return cell
    } else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Here's my cell's "configureCell" (not that it should matter)

```
func configureCell(cellNumber: Int) {
    backNumberLbl.text = "\(cellNumber)"
    frontNumberLbl.text = "\(cellNumber)"
    self.tag = cellNumber
    numberBtn.tag = cellNumber
}
```

I'm experiencing a visual problem, not a crash.  When I scroll, new cells are showing characteristics of cells that have scrolled off the screen.  I've changed the identifier, still broken.  And I changed it back, still broken.  I've commented out the other lines of code under the cell.configureCell(currentNumber).

I've searched all over and can't figure this out.

Thanks StackOverflow community!

Comment: Did you register `NumberCell` as `"NumberCell"` using `func registerClass(_:, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)`?

Comment: I am using a StoryBoard with a custom cell whose identifier is exactly "NumberCell"

Comment: What are the cells showing that appears from previous cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can`t add a comment because of my reputation.But I met a problem like this before.

1. If you use code, check if you have called method `public func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` in `viewDidLoad`.
2. if you use Nib, check if you have called method `registerNib(nib: UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`.
3. If you use a storyboard, do not call the method `public func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` or `registerNib`.

For more info, if broken(`I've changed the identifier, still broken`) means crashed, you`d better post the console logs.

Update:
I get the result as expected based on your code.Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NumberCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? NumberCell {
            let currentNumber = indexPath.row + 1
            cell.configureCell(currentNumber)
            cell.numberBtn.tag = currentNumber;
            cell.numberBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.playerClickedButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            return cell
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

    func playerClickedButton(button: UIButton) {
        print(button.tag)
    }

}

class NumberCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var backNumberLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var frontNumberLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberBtn: UIButton!

    func configureCell(cellNumber: Int) {
        backNumberLbl.text = "\(cellNumber)"
        frontNumberLbl.text = "\(cellNumber)"
        self.tag = cellNumber
        numberBtn.tag = cellNumber
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using a storyboard and as you can see in my above snippet, I'm not including that function.  Sorry, I should have been more clear.  "Broken", that doesn't mean crashed.  I means that it isn't dequeuing properly and I'm getting old cell visualizations in cells that show when scrolling the collection view.

Comment: @SZLSoft I update my answer. it works fine for me when scrolling.

Comment: Scrolling works fine.  The problem is that when a user taps a cell, it changes color.  Then, when they scroll, the new cells sometimes exhibit the color of the tapped cells.  So imagine you tap #3.  Then you scroll, and #40 might have the tapped color.  When you scroll back, #3 might be back to the original.

Comment: @SZLSoft That is another question.You can try :`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }`

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear...  When the user taps the cell, I manipulate the cell by changing color of the tapped item.  (The following #s are an example of the problem.  It's not always these numbers)  If they tap #3 and #5 while #38 and #40 are below the fold, the color for #3 and #5 are changed.  When the user scrolls, #3 and #5 go off the page, #38 and #40 show up as expected.  However, they have the changed color that #3 and #5 should have instead of the "untapped" color.  When they scroll back up to show #3 and #5, neither look tapped.

Comment: @SZLSoft `- (void)prepareForReuse` in NumberCell.

Answer (score -1):

let currentNumber = indexPath.row + 1

cell.configureCell(currentNumber)

here you are dequeuing a cell for current indexPath, but trying to configure next cell which has not been dequeued yet.

Comment: Actually, I'm dequeuing the cell, and configuring it.  The "currentNumber" is just an integer used in manipulation of a textfield for visual purposes.  It has nothing to do with the dequeueing.  I did try to take out the + 1 and the visual problem still happens